# Installing setuptools for python 2.7.3 on SL6 returns an error that I don't have zlib. But I do

Tags: python, zip, easy-install, scientific-linux

- I have a machine running Scientific Linux 6
- It comes with Python 2.6 by default
- I've also installed Python 2.7.3 because I need to run some modules which only work with newest versions. This is working nicely.
- I need to install more libraries for Python 2.7.3
- I'm trying to install setuptools in order to grab these modules

> [root@sa09b tmp]# wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
>
> [root@sa09b tmp]# python2.7 ez_setup.py Downloading
>
> http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ez_setup.py", line 278, in
>
> main(sys.argv[1:])   File "ez_setup.py", line 212, in main
>
> from setuptools.command.easy_install import main
>
> zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

oh? I thought I had that installed.

> [root@sa09b tmp]# yum install zlib Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
>
> Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>
> - sl: ftp1.scientificlinux.org
> - sl-security: ftp1.scientificlinux.org
>
> Setting up Install Process
>
> Package zlib-1.2.3-27.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
>
> Nothing to do

- So I looked up various forums
- Most tell me to install zlib-devel (done "Package zlib-devel-1.2.3-27.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version"), zlib1g ("No package zlib1g available."), zlib1g-devel (same as before).

Any ideas?

:-)

---

Edit:

```
[root@sa09b tmp]# zlib

-bash: zlib: command not found
```

could that be it?

---

Edit 2:

- So the line which fails is "from setuptools.command.easy_install import main"
- I think this is because the .egg file with setuptools needs to be extracted with zlib
- I tried installing pip, but that requires setuptools too.
- I can't use easy_install-2.7 for some reason. But easy_install for 2.6 works fine.

---

Edit 3:

"find" can't actually find anything to do with zlib in the system, other than python, despite yum saying its installed.

> ```
> [root@sa09b pip-1.2.1]# find / -name zlib
> /tmp/Python-2.7.3/Demo/zlib
> /tmp/Python-2.7.3/Modules/zlib
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer from another stackoverflow user.

Basically you can just copy zlib pre gcc'd from 2.6 to 2.7:

```
cp /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/zlibmodule.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/zlibmodule.so
```

Still hackish though.

Comment: Nice. This worked for me.

Comment: work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem. In my case the issue was that I had to install `zlib-devel` along other packages (see here http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/) before building Python-2.7. Once the packages are installed, running `./configure` for Python makes all the difference of detected libraries and subsequently `make && make altinstall` links them.

Answer (score 0):

You example of attempting to execute zlib does NOT indicate presence (or absence) of zlib...only that the zlib command does not exist.

zlib is simply a library of routines.

What you need to look at is what version of zlib needs to be installed and used by all the programs.  I suspect either the errant program is looking in the wrong place, or it needs a different version than is installed, or the program needing it is old and needs upgrading.

Comment: Please can you explain a bit further? I'm *really* stuck on this. (see second edit).